# change the value of a column imported in PBI from a PostgreSQL query based on conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql, powerquery

I need some help, I am not well versed in SQL and I am trying to fix an issue with some PBI here at work.

The case is the following, my PBI connects to a PostgreSQL to get the data for it's tables, on one of the tables however we have some rows that are miscategorized and that is causing some issues with the analysis. Since the rows are wrong on the DB I've contacted the DB manager however he does not want to change them in order to fix it. So I have to do something on my end.

This is my table in PBI:

[Table in PBI][image: 1]

In that table the column "subgrupo" should contain only "passaros" for that given "descpro" but they were miscategorized it as "suplementos".

In power query on PBI I have the following code to build up the aforementioned table from a Postgres

```
SELECT 
     internalproductid AS CODPRO
    ,ean AS EAN
        ,ncm AS NCM
    ,productdesc AS DESCPRO
    ,suppliername AS FORNECEDOR
    ,CASE
        WHEN UPPER(TRIM(productbrand)) = 'PETZ' THEN 'MP'
                ELSE 'OL'
    END AS MarcaPropria
    ,COALESCE(productbrand,' ')  AS MARCA
    ,CASE
        WHEN productstatus LIKE '1' THEN 'FL'
        ELSE 'AT'
    END AS FORA_LINHA
    ,N1    AS FAMILIA
    ,N2 AS GRUPO
    ,N3 AS SUBGRUPO
    ,buyergroup AS GRUPO_COMPRAS
    ,N4 AS Categoria_Modular
FROM tb_product
```

I need some extra code at "N3 AS SUBGRUPO" line, it should be something like:

IF N3 is "SUPLEMENTOS" AND productdesc contains 'ZOOTEKNA BST' it should bring Passaros AS "SUBGRUPO" ELSE it should bring N3 as is (as it is doing right now).

I believe that would fix that table, however I don't know how to structure this in Postgres. I was thinking about.

```
   CASE
        WHEN producdesc LIKE '%ZOOTEKNA BST%' 
        AND N3 like 'Suplementos'THEN 'Passaros'
        ELSE N3
    END AS SUBGRUPO
```

Not even sure if this works and not sure how to use a wildcard (I believe '%ZOOTEKNA BST%' is incorrect). Can someone give me a hand? Would the code above work and if not how should i do it?

Comment: I think that what you've written is right. One remark - when checking for equality better use `N3 = 'Suplementos'` instead of `N3 like 'Suplementos'`. The same with `productstatus = '1'`. And BTW after you finish your query and have it right why not make a view `tb_product_v` out of it and then use it instead of the table?

Comment: gonna try that, about using = instead of like are there any performance issues?

Comment: `=` is generally faster. I think that what really matters is that `like` usually defeats indexes. Please also note that you may use `ilike` if you need case-insensitive comparison. For more complex cases Postgres has a 'swiss knife' - [regular expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html).

Comment: Thank you!  it worked ! And now I know a lil bit more about SQL and postgre